# C# EntityFramework 4.1 set database to update mode

Tags: c#, entity-framework-4.1

Is it possible to set the database to update? Like in java where we can set hibernate's property hbm2ddl.auto=update.

The reason is because I already have the database setup and have an application using it program using model first strategy. Now I want to try the new EntityFramework 4.1 release and CodeFirst strategy. I don't want to drop-create my database as I already have data in it so the only option is to update, create/update the new tables automatically.

Thanks,
czetsuya

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For CodeFirst the Entity Framework team is currently working on [Code First Migrations](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2011/09/21/code-first-migrations-alpha-3-released.aspx)
It's still in Alpha but you can already give it a try to migrate your database.